# attribute that will wrap all methods in class with try { } catch

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to create an attribute `HandleError` that I would put on a class like this:

```
[HandleError]
public class Foo
{
   public void Do(){}
...
   public void Don(){}
}
```

and it will wrap all the methods in try catch, so I believe it should be something like this:

```
public class HandleErrorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public void Execute()
    {    
        try
        {
            method.Execute();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log
        }
    }
}
```

is this possible ?

Comment: With the current framework, no. It might be possible with one of the AOP libraries though.  http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net

Comment: That is not what attributes do. As @asawyer notes, postsharp can allow this; and in future versions, this sort of thing might be possible as an extension thanks to the compiler rewrite (aka Roslyn); but at the moment: no

Comment: @MarcGravell, do you think this will be built in because of Roslyn or do you think we'll have to build an open source project for it?

Comment: @MarcGravell, side bar, I'm the one that sent you an email a week or so ago about using the multi-query functionality in Dapper. I did end up just making multiple round-trips so that I could reuse some code easier in the application, Dapper is just so ridiculously fast it doesn't make a difference, great job on Dapper friend!

Comment: @BigM no, I don't expect that to be "built in", but it looks like the sort of thing that might be *possible* via Roslyn as an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like PostSharp, and it's well worth implementing. However, the implementation is far beyond the scope of this question. Take a look at this [link](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-6-Your-code-after-PostSharp.aspx), you'll see it's doing just what you want.

So, download PostSharp, get started with it, and if you have more questions about it then we'd be able to help you out. However, their documentation is insanely good and it's cake to implement.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyExceptionHandling : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // here you would perform the logging
    }
}
```

Then on your method you would mark it up with the new attribute:

```
public class Foo
{
    [MyExceptionHandling]
    public void Do(){}
    [MyExceptionHandling]
    public void Don(){}
}
```

Comment: so how would this attribute be written using postsharp ?

Comment: @ChuckNorris, by implementing the `OnException` method it gets wrapped in a `try-catch` block by PostSharp so that PostSharp can allow you to handle it.

Comment: ok, so if don't do throw inside the OnException, the exception won't go further

Comment: @ChuckNorris, as far as that's concerned, you'll need to brush up on the documentation for PostSharp, but I think the command you're looking for is `args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without PostSharp, but keeping the IL transform?

Comment: @Silvio, you could of course implement your own IL injection, but I don't think that's a reasonable solution. Is there a real compelling reason you want what PostSharp offers but don't want to use PostSharp?

Comment: PostSharp requires commercial licensing. Doesn't really help.